Cómo se elabora un cuadro con porcentajes y se grafican las leyendas para un diagrama ternario realizado con TTplot?
A partir de un data frame donde se encuentran las especies de nematodos en distintos sitios intento realizar un cuadro con porcentajes para cada grupo trófico y esto representarlo en un diagrama ternario. Esto es lo que conseguí hacer:
library(soiltexture)
help(TT.plot)
mis.datos<-data.frame(
  "Fitoparásitos"=c(8.77,58.05,7.36),
  "Bacteriófagos"=c(91.23,41.95,91.57),
  "Omnívoros"=c(0,0,1.07),
  "Huella_de_carbono"=c(420.38,251.01,662.03)
)
TT.plot(
  class.sys = "none",
  lang = "es2",
  main = "Huellas de carbono",
  lwd.axis = 0.5,
  cex.lab = 0.8,
  cex.axis = 0.8,
  css.names = c("Fitoparásitos","Bacteriófagos","Omnívoros"),
  css.lab = c("Fitoparásitos","Bacteriófagos","Omnívoros"),
  tri.data = mis.datos,
  z.name = "Huella_de_carbono",
)

En este ejemplo yo tuve que calcular los porcentajes, la idea es evitar esto para automatizar el proceso.
Saludos.
Sá, Farid Leonel.

Es más fácil ayudarte si proporcionas un ejemplo de cómo son tus datos originales con los cuales obtuviste los porcentajes para indicarte la mejor manera de automatizar el cálculo.

mis.datos<-data.frame("Fitoparasitos"=c(570,2297,768),"Bacteriófagos"=c(276,113,420),"Omnívoros"=c(0,0,5),"Huella_de_carbono"=c(420.38,251.01,662.03))

Tus porcentajes no coinciden con estos valores de la tabla. ¿podrías indicar cómo calculaste dichos porcentajes?

Fitoparásitos = (( Fitoparásitos )/ (Fitoparásitos +Bacteriófagos + Omnívoros)) *100, Bacteriófagos =((Bacteriófagos)/(Fitoparásitos + Bacteriófagos + Omnívoros))*100, Omnívoros = ((Omnívoros)/(Fitoparásitos + Bacteriófagos +Omnívoros))*100

Aquí te dejo una versión 'automática' para:

Obtener los porcentajes (con prop.table) según filas (margin=1).
Establecer las etiquetas del gráfico según los nombres de las variables de tu tabla de datos (names(datos_ttplot))

El código quedaría de esta manera:
library(soiltexture)

datos_ttplot <- data.frame(
  prop.table(as.matrix(mis.datos[,-4]), margin = 1)*100, 
  mis.datos[, 4, drop = FALSE])


nombres_ttplot <- names(datos_ttplot)

TT.plot(  class.sys = "none",
          lang = "es2",
          main = "Huellas de carbono",
          lwd.axis = 0.5,
          cex.lab = 0.8,
          cex.axis = 0.8,
          css.names = nombres_ttplot[-4],
          css.lab =  nombres_ttplot[-4],
          tri.data = datos_ttplot,
          z.name = nombres_ttplot[4])

Lo que produce:


Gracias por tu ayuda @JilberUrbina
